# d3.js Animation not working for all the iterations of loop

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-animations

I am building a d3js liquid fill visualization as mentioned in http://jsfiddle.net/zm5p9LLe/. The example shows one liquid fill gauge. I am looping in and creating multiple gauges. But, the animation works only for last iteration of the loop. Is this due to the common div id for a transition? do we have any alternates to make animation work in all the gauges?

**HTML**

```
<svg id="fillgauge1" width="97%" height="250"></svg>
```

**CSS**

```
.liquidFillGaugeText {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge1", 45.34);


function liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings() {
    return {
        minValue: 0, // The gauge minimum value.
        maxValue: 100, // The gauge maximum value.
        circleThickness: 0.05, // The outer circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
        circleFillGap: 0.05, // The size of the gap between the outer circle and wave circle as a percentage of the outer circles radius.
        circleColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the outer circle.
        waveHeight: 0.05, // The wave height as a percentage of the radius of the wave circle.
        waveCount: 3, // The number of full waves per width of the wave circle.
        waveRiseTime: 1000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for the wave to rise from 0 to it's final height.
        waveAnimateTime: 1000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for a full wave to enter the wave circle.
        waveRise: true, // Control if the wave should rise from 0 to it's full height, or start at it's full height.
        waveHeightScaling: true, // Controls wave size scaling at low and high fill percentages. When true, wave height reaches it's maximum at 50% fill, and minimum at 0% and 100% fill. This helps to prevent the wave from making the wave circle from appear totally full or empty when near it's minimum or maximum fill.
        waveAnimate: true, // Controls if the wave scrolls or is static.
        waveColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the fill wave.
        waveOffset: 0.25, // The amount to initially offset the wave. 0 = no offset. 1 = offset of one full wave.
        textVertPosition: .8, // The height at which to display the percentage text withing the wave circle. 0 = bottom, 1 = top.
        textSize: 0.6, // The relative height of the text to display in the wave circle. 1 = 50%
        valueCountUp: true, // If true, the displayed value counts up from 0 to it's final value upon loading. If false, the final value is displayed.
        displayPercent: true, // If true, a % symbol is displayed after the value.
        textColor: "#045681", // The color of the value text when the wave does not overlap it.
        waveTextColor: "#A4DBf8" // The color of the value text when the wave overlaps it.
    };
}

function loadLiquidFillGauge(elementId, value, config) {
    if (config == null) config = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();

    var gauge = d3.select("#" + elementId);
    var radius = Math.min(parseInt(gauge.style("width")), parseInt(gauge.style("height"))) / 2;
    var locationX = parseInt(gauge.style("width")) / 2 - radius;
    var locationY = parseInt(gauge.style("height")) / 2 - radius;
    var fillPercent = Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value)) / config.maxValue;

    var waveHeightScale;
    if (config.waveHeightScaling) {
        waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, config.waveHeight, 0])
            .domain([0, 50, 100]);
    } else {
        waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([config.waveHeight, config.waveHeight])
            .domain([0, 100]);
    }

    var textPixels = (config.textSize * radius / 2);
    var textFinalValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    var textStartValue = config.valueCountUp ? config.minValue : textFinalValue;
    var percentText = config.displayPercent ? "%" : "";
    var circleThickness = config.circleThickness * radius;
    var circleFillGap = config.circleFillGap * radius;
    var fillCircleMargin = circleThickness + circleFillGap;
    var fillCircleRadius = radius - fillCircleMargin;
    var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius * waveHeightScale(fillPercent * 100);

    var waveLength = fillCircleRadius * 2 / config.waveCount;
    var waveClipCount = 1 + config.waveCount;
    var waveClipWidth = waveLength * waveClipCount;

    // Rounding functions so that the correct number of decimal places is always displayed as the value counts up.
    var textRounder = function (value) {
        return Math.round(value);
    };
    if (parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))) {
        textRounder = function (value) {
            return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
        };
    }
    if (parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))) {
        textRounder = function (value) {
            return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
        };
    }

    // Data for building the clip wave area.
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 40 * waveClipCount; i++) {
        data.push({
            x: i / (40 * waveClipCount),
            y: (i / (40))
        });
    }

    // Scales for drawing the outer circle.
    var gaugeCircleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]).domain([0, 1]);
    var gaugeCircleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, radius]);

    // Scales for controlling the size of the clipping path.
    var waveScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0, waveClipWidth]).domain([0, 1]);
    var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0, waveHeight]).domain([0, 1]);

    // Scales for controlling the position of the clipping path.
    var waveRiseScale = d3.scale.linear()
    // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
    // such that the it will won't overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
    // circle at 100%.
    .range([(fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight), (fillCircleMargin - waveHeight)])
        .domain([0, 1]);
    var waveAnimateScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, waveClipWidth - fillCircleRadius * 2]) // Push the clip area one full wave then snap back.
    .domain([0, 1]);

    // Scale for controlling the position of the text within the gauge.
    var textRiseScaleY = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2, (fillCircleMargin + textPixels * 0.7)])
        .domain([0, 1]);

    // Center the gauge within the parent SVG.
    var gaugeGroup = gauge.append("g")
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + locationX + ',' + locationY + ')');

    // Draw the outer circle.
    var gaugeCircleArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(gaugeCircleX(0))
        .endAngle(gaugeCircleX(1))
        .outerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius))
        .innerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius - circleThickness));
    gaugeGroup.append("path")
        .attr("d", gaugeCircleArc)
        .style("fill", config.circleColor)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');

    // Text where the wave does not overlap.
    var text1 = gaugeGroup.append("text")
        .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
        .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
        .style("fill", config.textColor)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition) + ')');

    // The clipping wave area.
    var clipArea = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function (d) {
        return waveScaleX(d.x);
    })
        .y0(function (d) {
        return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * config.waveOffset * -1 + Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.waveCount) + d.y * 2 * Math.PI));
    })
        .y1(function (d) {
        return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
    });
    var waveGroup = gaugeGroup.append("defs")
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clipWave" + elementId);
    var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("d", clipArea);

    // The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
    var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipWave" + elementId + ")");
    fillCircleGroup.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", radius)
        .attr("cy", radius)
        .attr("r", fillCircleRadius)
        .style("fill", config.waveColor);

    // Text where the wave does overlap.
    var text2 = fillCircleGroup.append("text")
        .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
        .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
        .style("fill", config.waveTextColor)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition) + ')');

    // Make the value count up.
    if (config.valueCountUp) {
        var textTween = function () {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, textFinalValue);
            return function (t) {
                this.textContent = textRounder(i(t)) + percentText;
            }
        };
        text1.transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .tween("text", textTween);
        text2.transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .tween("text", textTween);
    }

    // Make the wave rise. wave and waveGroup are separate so that horizontal and vertical movement can be controlled independently.
    var waveGroupXPosition = fillCircleMargin + fillCircleRadius * 2 - waveClipWidth;
    if (config.waveRise) {
        waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(0) + ')')
            .transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(fillPercent) + ')')
            .each("start", function () {
            wave.attr('transform', 'translate(1,0)');
        }); // This transform is necessary to get the clip wave positioned correctly when waveRise=true and waveAnimate=false. The wave will not position correctly without this, but it's not clear why this is actually necessary.
    } else {
        waveGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveGroupXPosition + ',' + waveRiseScale(fillPercent) + ')');
    }

    if (config.waveAnimate) animateWave();

    function animateWave() {
        wave.transition()
            .duration(config.waveAnimateTime)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(1) + ',0)')
            .each("end", function () {
            wave.attr('transform', 'translate(' + waveAnimateScale(0) + ',0)');
            animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id. I think everything works fine when you have multiple gauges with unique ids. Could you provide code of not working example on jsfiddle? Maybe we will be able to find solution.